# How to set array of objects in environment variable for docker

Tags: c#, arrays, docker, object, environment-variables

I have an object like the below in `application.json` and would like to set those in as environment variables so that I don't have to deploy the code all the time.

```
  "Player": [
    {
      "Location": "Moon",
      "TipType": "Cash",
      "Duty": "manager"
    },
    {
      "Location": "Sun",
      "TipType": "Free",
      "Duty": "Supervisor"
    }
  ],
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Any help suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's as simple as replacing your config code in your app with calls to System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, and passing variables with docker run -e. To be honest I much prefer to have my appSettings.json, and then replace that with a docker mount -v, this allows me to replace the appSettings.json file with each docker run.